# how to access xml nodes in flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, parsing

A web service return to my flex3 client this custom exception:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:ro="urn:Gov2gLibrary" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:HNS="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v1="http://tempuri.org/">
 <faultcode>E2gError</faultcode>
 <faultstring>abc</faultstring>
 <detail>
  <HNS:ROException>
   <HNS:Messages>
    <HNS:T2gMsg>
     <HNS:ID>4545</HNS:ID>
     <HNS:Severity>abc</HNS:Severity>
     <HNS:Category>abc</HNS:Category>
     <HNS:Message1>abc</HNS:Message1>
     <HNS:Message2 />
    </HNS:T2gMsg>
    <HNS:T2gMsg>
     <HNS:ID>345344</HNS:ID>
     <HNS:Severity>abc</HNS:Severity>
     <HNS:Category>abc</HNS:Category>
     <HNS:Message1>abc</HNS:Message1>
     <HNS:Message2 />
    </HNS:T2gMsg>
   </HNS:Messages>
  </HNS:ROException>
 </detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

This is obviously a part of the FaultEvent object I get when the remote call fail, so I'm trying to access "T2gMsg" subnode values like this:

```
protected function onFaultEvent(e:FaultEvent):void
{
 var obj:Object = e.fault;
 var err:XMLList = obj.element.detail.children()[0].children();
 // now I have in err the "Messages" list, subnode of ROException,
 // so I should cycle to read one message at time:
 for each (var x:XML in err.children())
 {
  //?
 }
```

Now I can't figure out how to read ID, Severity etc values. I think something like "x.ID" should work but it's not, while x.child("ID") or x.elements("ID") return null. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(as suggested I'm moving here the solution I founded to close the question)

it was a matter of namespaces: [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13%5FWorking%5Fwith%5FXML%5F09.html) explain we need to qualify nodes to access them:

```
var obj:Object = e.fault;
var doc:XML = obj.element.detail[0];
var err:XMLList = doc.children()[0].children(); // messages
var ns:Namespace = doc.namespace("HNS");
for each (var x:XML in err.children())
{
    trace(x.ns::ID);
    trace(x.ns::Severity);
    trace(x.ns::Category);
    trace(x.ns::Message1);
    trace(x.ns::Message2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your xml uses namespaces, so you can try to access `someNode.name().localName` to dig deep inside, and use text() to get the value

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    if (x[i].name().localName == "ID")  trace('x["ID"]: ' + x[i].text());
}
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand, I know XML(x.children()[0]).localName().toString() -> "ID", but I want to access the ID value by name, like x.ID or x["ID"] or x.some_method("ID"), not by index.

Comment: I guess there will be a bit of if/else action going on.

Comment: why don't you answer your question with the solution you found? putting it as part of the question is not an obvious place for the question (not to mention that the question remains without an accepted answer...)

Answer (score 0):

thanks. along with the online doc and this discussion I understand how to access the namespace xml nodes.
I guess, if a prefix is not used as the below example xml, you need to assign the namespace for the uri being used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <FindJunctionResponse xmlns="http://someserver/Service/NamePath">
      <FindJunctionResult>
        <OID>558</OID>
        <ClassID>5</ClassID>
        <Position>0</Position>
        <EID>0</EID>
        <XCoord>1662634.10015</XCoord>
        <YCoord>71634.435475</YCoord>
        <IsJunction>true</IsJunction>
        <IsFlag>false</IsFlag>
      </FindJunctionResult>
    </FindJunctionResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope
```

So even though it's a little long, the "syntax" to access the xml nodes would be:

```
<xml message>.<namespace class>::<xml node>.<name space class>
```

....

```
private function webServiceHandleResult(event:ResultEvent):void
{                            
    XML.ignoreWhitespace;
    var eXml:XML = new XML(event.message.body);
    var eXmlList:XMLList = eXml.children();
    var soapNS:Namespace = eXml.namespace("soap");
    var xmlnsNS:Namespace = new Namespace("http://someserver/Service/NamePath/")
    var resulteXmlList:XMLList = eXml.soapNS::Body.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResponse.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResult;
    for each (var myxml:XML in resulteXmlList.children())
    {
        //for each field, you can get the name and the value
        trace("field: " + myxml.localName() + ": " + myxml.valueOf());
    }
    //or reference each xml node by name.
    trace("OID: " = eXml.soapNS::Body.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResponse.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResult.xmlnsNS::OID);
    trace("ClassID: " = eXml.soapNS::Body.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResponse.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResult.xmlnsNS::ClassID);
    trace("Position: " = eXml.soapNS::Body.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResponse.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResult.xmlnsNS::Position);
    trace("EID: " = eXml.soapNS::Body.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResponse.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResult.xmlnsNS::EID);
    trace("XCoord: " = eXml.soapNS::Body.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResponse.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResult.xmlnsNS::XCoord);    
    trace("YCoord: " = eXml.soapNS::Body.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResponse.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResult.xmlnsNS::YCoord);    
    trace("IsJunction: " = eXml.soapNS::Body.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResponse.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResult.xmlnsNS::IsJunction);
    trace("IsFlag: " = eXml.soapNS::Body.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResponse.xmlnsNS::FindJunctionResult.xmlnsNS::IsFlag);    
}
```